# Localhost Not Found Xampp

Tags: xampp

I used xampp 2-3 months ago ... now I want to use it again and I have the same projects in the same folders but when I try to access localhost i recive a 404 Not Found error. I don't understant why I have this error because I didn't changed anything.

I have ServerName localhost in httpd.conf.

I didn't change anything ... Why now isn't working?

Thank you

Edit:

Restarting web server apache2                                                AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: what is the output pf you /etc/hosts

Comment: `127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 cristi-desktop

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

This is what I have inside etc/hosts`

Comment: ok i will post a sloution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here is your solution :

change the port number used by **apache** configuration file from 80 to 8080 by this command and you can change it inside **ports.conf** :

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

restart apache .

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Try it

```
Type localhost:8080/ and try
```

Comment: welcome man happy it work for you